# Type coercion in Perl6

Tags: raku, coercion

If I have an an object of type Str, and I want to coerce it into an Int, it is my understanding that I can do this by calling the method Int on the Str-object, like so:

`"100".Int`

I (think I) know I can do this because the Str-type documentation at https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str lists the Int-method. Now, to coerce this newly created Int into an object of type Complex, I tried the following coercion:

`"100".Int.Complex`

which works :-) So no problem. Except that I can't figure out why it works. The Int-type documentation at https://docs.perl6.org/type/Int does not list a method Complex. I did find a method with this name for the class ComplexStr, but I have no clue if this is somehow relevant to my Int, or not.

So the question is: how does the above coercion work? Where does the method Complex come from? And how could I have known I can actually call it on an Int-object before trying?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is merely a case of incomplete documentation.

You can always find out what methods an object supports by calling `.^methods` on it:

```
perl6 -e '$_>>.name.join(", ").say for 123.^methods.sort(*.name).rotor(5 => 0, :partial)'
ACCEPTS, Bool, Bridge, Capture, Complex
DUMP, FatRat, Int, Num, Numeric
Range, Rat, Real, Str, WHICH
abs, acos, acosec, acosech, acosh
acotan, acotanh, asec, asech, asin
asinh, atan, atan2, atanh, base
ceiling, chr, cis, conj, cos
cosec, cosech, cosh, cotan, cotanh
exp, expmod, floor, gist, is-prime
isNaN, log, log10, lsb, msb
narrow, new, perl, polymod, pred
rand, roots, round, sec, sech
sign, sin, sinh, sqrt, succ
```

In the mean time, I [pushed a commit to the docs repo](https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/74902c6eb761f4ec01ecac2fe7a2daa9f7da025a) that adds the missing method. The website is already regenerated with the change: https://docs.perl6.org/type/Int#(Real)_method_Complex

Comment: The command should be perl6 -e '$_>>.name.join(", ").say for 123.^methods.sort(*.name).rotor(5 , :partial)' otherwise you are missing the last four methods tan, tanh, truncate, unpolar

Answer (score 3):

(This is more an extended comment than an answer. I know only Perl 5.)

From https://docs.perl6.org/type/Cool:

> Methods in Cool coerce the invocant to a more specific type, and then
>   call the same method on that type. For example both Int and Str
>   inherit from Cool, and calling method substr on an Int converts the
>   integer to Str first.
>
> ```
> 123.substr(1, 1);   # '2', same as 123.Str.substr(1, 1)
> ```

So it seems that `123.substr(1, 1)` is like `Cool(123).substr(1, 1)` in a more traditional notation, which is then rewritten to `Str(123).substr(1, 1)` because `Str` inherits from `Cool` (like the classical OOP done backward).

In a similar way, it seems that `"100".Int.Complex` is like `Cool("100").Int.Complex -> Int("100").Complex -> 100.Complex -> Cool(100).Complex -> Complex(100)`.

Comment: In the REPL, `123.WHAT` returns `(Int)`, and the Int-type documentation makes it clear that one can call the routine substr on an Int since the routine is inherited from/provided by Cool. So the example you mentioned seems covered by the docs in a straightforward fashion. `"100".WHAT`, however returns `(Str)`, while `"100".Int` returns `(Int)` as predicted by the Str-type documentation. But then the Int-type documentation does not list method Complex; neither does the Cool-type documentation. So I'm lost at stage 100.Complex.

Comment: hi @Ozzy - I like to look at the Type Graph in the perl6 docs - here is one from ComplexStr - but you may want to start from another point https://docs.perl6.org/type/ComplexStr#Type_Graph